# Edit ObservableCollection field

Tags: windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I have ObservableCollection with 3 columns: id, name, image.

First two are filed with data from db and I want to fill the last one with my data. In image column I would like to put some static part + id

Is it possible?

I assume that some for loop will do the job, but don't know where to start

EDIT - MY CODE:

Object:

```
public class HabitatDB
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string imagelink { get; set; }
    }
```

Getting data:

```
ObservableCollection<HabitatDB> _habitatEntries = null;

private void GetHabitats()
        {
            string strSelect = "SELECT id, name FROM habitat ORDER BY id ASC";
            _habitatEntries = (Application.Current as App).db.SelectObservableCollection<HabitatDB>(strSelect);

            HabitatListBox.ItemsSource = _habitatEntries;

        }
```

Comment: show the code how you are filling the data from db. then we can help you out on filling the 3rd part

Comment: Okay, I added some code. I'm using SQLite if that matters smth

Answer (score 0):

I lost almost whole day and by accident I found REALLY simple solution...

Just a small change in class and you don't need to mess with ObservableCollection AT ALL.

```
public class HabitatDB
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string imagelink { get { return string.Format("graphics/habitats/{0}.png", id); } }
}
```

Then just `<Image Source="{Binding imagelink}"/>`